# Send a mail from shell script in Ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu, smtp, sendmail

I have created one shell script which performs some database query and created a cron tab to execute that shell script. I am generating log for this task to check whether script is executed successfully or not.
Now I want to send this log file to developer using **smtp** ?
How can I configure **smtp** in shell script ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use SendEmail script (https://github.com/mogaal/sendemail)

It is a very good command line smtp client. YoU can run it from crontab. Example usage:

```
sendEmail -f fromAddr@example.com -t toAddr@example.com -s smtp.server.com -u theSubject -m the Message -a fileToAttach
```

Description from official site:

> SendEmail is a lightweight, command line SMTP email client. If you
> have the need to send email from a command line, this free program is
> perfect: simple to use and feature rich. It was designed to be used in
> bash scripts, batch files, Perl programs and web sites, but is quite
> adaptable and will likely meet your requirements. SendEmail is written
> in Perl and is unique in that it requires NO MODULES. It has an
> intuitive and flexible set of command-line options, making it very
> easy to learn and use.
>
> SendEmail is licensed under the GNU GPL, either version 2 of the
> License or (at your option) any later version.
>
> [Supported Platforms: Linux, BSD, OS X, Windows 98, Windows NT,
> Windows 2000, & Windows XP]

Comment: Is there any other way to send mail, without configuring smpt client ?

Comment: You don't need to configure anything. Just download sendemail and execute it as in the example. It will connect to given smtp server and send the e-mail.

Comment: link is dead :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to send an email from the command line, or from a shell script:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail recipient@domain.tld < /path/to/message/to/send.txt
```